# Cannot create proper tables with libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to create a table that's going to be like this:

```
| xxxxxxxxx |
| x | x | x |
....
```

and i've written this code to do it, but instead it goes all wrong and doesn't come out anything like i would...

```
    Label label = new Label("ORTHO", style);
    label.setWrap(true);
    label.setWidth(100);

    Label label1 = new Label("A", style);
    label1.setWrap(true);
    label1.setWidth(100);

    Label label2 = new Label("A", style);
    label2.setWrap(true);
    label2.setWidth(100);

    table.row();
    table.add(new Label(label.getText(), style)).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-100);

    table.row();
    table.add(new Label(label1.getText(), style)).width(50).align(Align.left);
    table.add(new Label(label2.getText(), style)).width(50).align(Align.left);

    table.debug();
    stage.addActor(table);
```

any ideas?

Comment: how does it come out? and why are you creating a new label based off of the labels data...?

Answer (score 2):

**What you need here is [colspan](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout)**

`colspan(int n)` makes the item being added to span across n columns.

So you have to apply it on the first label's add method call.

---

Also, don't create new labels while adding. Since you have already instantiated them, you can use them while adding. (Also don't use `setWidth` as you'll specify width while adding).

```
// Create
Label label = new Label("ORTHO", style);
label.setWrap(true);

Label label1 = new Label("A", style);
label1.setWrap(true);

Label label2 = new Label("A", style);
label2.setWrap(true);

// Add
table.add(label).width(100).colspan(2);
table.row();

table.add(label1).width(50).align(Align.left);
table.add(label2).width(50).align(Align.left);
```